# Sorted X axis ticks in Matplotlib when using multiple datasets

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have several datasets that I want to plot. The x values are "categorical" strings, in the sense that they have no particularly meaning, but they are sortable (alphanumeric). Each dataset has some X values that are unique, and some that are in common. The desired output is a graph where the xXtick labels are in sorted order.

Unfortunately I can't find a way to tell matplotlib what I want. It properly combines the Y values on the common X values, but puts the unique X values in the later datasets on the right side of the graph.

Here's an example to illustrate the issue:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Create first data set
x1 = np.array(['a', 'c', 'e'])
y1 = np.array([1, 2, 5])

# Create second data set with some x values in common with first dataset
x2 = np.array(['a', 'b', 'd', 'e'])
y2 = np.array([2, 4, 1, 1])

# Plot both datasets
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x1, y1, color='r', marker='+', linestyle='None')
ax.plot(x2, y2, color='b', marker='o', linestyle='None')
```

This results in the graph below.

[image]

The values for "a" and "e" are properly combined for both datasets. But I'd like to have "b" and "d" show up in sorted order, such that the X tick labels are "a", "b", "c", "d", "e". I can produce a combined sorted set of X values using

```
sorted_x = np.sort(np.unique(np.hstack([x1, x2]))))
```

But I'm unsure how to leverage this to tell matplotlib this is the desired order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first add a dummy plot using the x-values in the desired order. The following code creates the dummy plot, setting the x-values in the desired order. The plot is removed immediately to prevent that it interferes with other matplotlib functions.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Create first data set
x1 = np.array(['a', 'c', 'e'])
y1 = np.array([1, 2, 5])

# Create second data set with some x values in common with first dataset
x2 = np.array(['a', 'b', 'd', 'e'])
y2 = np.array([2, 4, 1, 1])

# Plot both datasets
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

sorted_x = np.sort(np.unique(np.hstack([x1, x2])))

sorted_x = np.sort(np.unique(np.hstack([x1, x2])))
# create a dummy plot with the x-values in the desired order, and then remove the plot
ax.plot(sorted_x, np.full(len(sorted_x), np.NaN), color='none')[0].remove()
ax.plot(x1, y1, color='r', marker='+', linestyle='None')
ax.plot(x2, y2, color='b', marker='o', linestyle='None')
plt.show()
```

[image: categorical x-axis sorted]